# regarding chocolate chip cookies

Tags: chocolate

I use the chocolate chip recipe on the bag but double the vanilla and add more chips than called for. I also add a bit more flour.   What I want to achieve is that old time chocolate chip cookie that is chewy flat and wide.  Can you offer a suggestion.  I still would use more chips and vanilla unless that might cause a problem.
I am so glad I came apon your sight.

Comment: Hello Baker2, we find it best when all the solutions to one problem are in the same place, so we close duplicate questions. This way the next guy can find everything he searches for, instead of hearing "we've answered this a thousand times already". For the future, please add more information to your questions - if it had not been a duplicate, nobody would have known what you are doing to begin with, as people don't know your recipe.

Answer (score 0):

I usually stick with the venerable Alton Brown's 'The Chewy' recipe:

http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/alton-brown/the-chewy-recipe.html

I often add a few extra tablespoons of wheat-gluten to make them even chewier.

You could reduce the amount of leavening (i.e. the baking soda (or any baking powder)) if you want a flatter cookie, but my results with the above recipe end-up pretty flat. Adding more vanilla and chips shouldn't make any difference in the end-product's texture, but I'd stick to the formula on flour for your first try.